# When using passport.js and ngrok, req.user is undefined because of cors

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, ngrok

The frontend is http localhost and the backend is https ngrok. When I log in with OAuth in the frontend and try to call req.user in the backend, it says undefined.

Also, if both the backend and the frontend use ngrok, the same problem occurs. However, if I do not use ngrok in the backend and use the localhost which is http, everything works fine.

ngrok command: `ngrok --host-header http 8000`

Express: app.ts

```
import "~/database";
import "~/libs/passport";

import express from "express";
import session from "express-session";
import cors from "cors";
import passport from "passport";
import { router } from "~/routes";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({ secret: "asdf", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));

app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/", router);
app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server has been started...");
});
```

React: App.tsx

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const handleSignIn = useCallback(() => {
    window.location.assign("http://localhost:8000/api/auth");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const process = async () => {
      const result = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/profile", {
        credentials: "include",
      });
      console.log(await result.json());
    };

    process();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <button onClick={handleSignIn}>DASD</button>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

There's no error, but req.user is undefined.

/api/auth

```
api.get("/", passport.authenticate("github", { scope: ["repo"] }));
```

/api/auth/callback

```
api.get(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("github", {
    failureRedirect: failureURL,
    successRedirect: frontendOrigin,
  })
);
```

Add: and call /api/profile in frontend, status is 401.

/api/profile

```
api.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.status(401).json();
  }

  const profile: Profile = {
    username: req.user.username,
    name: req.user.name,
    avatarURL: req.user.avatarURL,
  };
  return res.status(200).json(profile);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't

https://ngrok.com/docs/faq

> CORS with HTTP Basic Authentication
>
> ngrok's HTTP tunnels will work with CORS, but you cannot use ngrok's
> --basic-auth option. ngrok's HTTP tunnels allow you to specify basic authentication credentials to protect your tunnels. However, ngrok
> enforces this policy on all requests, including the preflight OPTIONS
> requests that are required by the CORS spec. In this case, your
> application must implement its own basic authentication.

It might be because you yuse `credentials: true`, ngrok already uses `--basic-auth` option.

Can you share the error thrown ?

Comment: if I don't use credentials: true, browser says Access to fetch at 'https://b3db-115-136-10-6.jp.ngrok.io/api/profile' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Comment: Can you try `app.use(cors({ origin: false, credentials: true }));` in order to disable CORS completely https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options with this parameter it should really block :)

Comment: otherwise try to remove the middleware

Comment: Was there ever an answer?